# Programa para automação de processo

Tags: python, automatização

Estou escrevendo um programa em Python para automatizar uma das rotinas do meu trabalho.

Mas eu me deparei com uma parte em que não consigo continuar, vejam:

Nessa etapa, eu preciso escrever um código que identifique o menor valor das colunas 1, 3 e 5 em cada linha do `DataFrame` abaixo, e quanto encontrar o menor valor, retorne a string contida na coluna seguinte, e na mesma linha, do valor encontrado, e salve tudo em um segundo `DataFrame`.

`DataFrame` que estou utilizando (pandas) como exemplo neste caso é o seguinte:

[image: Data Frame DF3]

Link com os dados: [Dados(google drive)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iVTxpYRru9AA9QQIfjXWe_lxSlnhny_o/view?usp=sharing)

O resultado esperado aqui seria um dataframe contendo a seguinte informação:

```
4bio
expressa
4bio
4bio
4bio
4bio
```

Mas mesmo pesquisando vários dias, estou bem longe do meu objetivo. Até agora, o máximo que consegui escrever, e não funcionou nem de longe foi:

```
    resultado = []
for i in df3:
    if i == df3.min (axis = 1):
        resultado.append(i)
```

Eu peço que tenham um pouco de compreensão, é o primeiro programa que tento escrever, e realmente estou travado nessa tarefa.

Desde já agradeço muito.

Comment: Se os dados estivessem na forma de texto eu até responderia, pois seria apenas o caso de copiar e colar os dados criar um DataFrame e aplicar a solução. Mas como é uma imagem teria que escrever valor após valor, linha após linha para ai então resolver o problema.

Comment: Boa tarde Augusto. Eu tentei colar em formato tabela, mas tinha perdido a formatação, então achei que ficaria mais fácil como imagem, me desculpe, vou tentar novamente:

Comment: vl_proposto_4bio distribuidor_4bio vl_proposto_expressa distribuidor_expressa vl_proposto_pfizer distribuidor_pfizer
50 4bio 70 expressa 50 pfizer
80 4bio 40 expressa 80 pfizer
30 4bio 50 expressa - pfizer
1200 4bio 1300 expressa 1200 pfizer
300 4bio 500 expressa 300 pfizer
200 4bio 250 expressa - pfizer

Comment: Subi os dados para o link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iVTxpYRru9AA9QQIfjXWe_lxSlnhny_o/view?usp=sharing vou incluir na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi bem o que você quer fazer, eu achei a seguinte solução:

```
resultado = []
for row in range(0, len(df.index)): 
    menor = df.iloc[row, 0]
    col_menor = 0
    for col in range(0, len(df.columns), 2):
        if df.iloc[row, col] != '-' and df.iloc[row, col] < menor:
            menor = df.iloc[row, col]
            col_menor = col
    resultado.append(df.iloc[row, col_menor + 1])
```

O primeiro `for` passa por cada linha do Dataframe (usei um `range` para garantir que sejam valores numéricos, caso você opte por alterar o index). A variável `menor` inicia com o primeiro valor daquela linha.

O segundo `for` passa entre as colunas, uma sim, uma não, para pular aquelas que tem apenas strings.

A variável `col_menor` armazena a posição da coluna que contém o menor valor naquela linha.

Após a verificar se é o menor número (caso seja diferente de ' - '), o valor da coluna após a do menor número é passada para a lista `resultado`.

Obs: No seu dataframe há valores iguais na mesma linha, em colunas diferentes, atente-se a isso.

Comment: Meu caro, não tenho como agradecer pela ajuda, é exatamente o que eu precisava.

Comment: Apliquei no código e funcionou perfeitamente. Agora vou estudar esse código pra entender perfeitamente o que ele está fazendo. Uma últiam dúvida: é esperado eu ter valores iguais na mesma linha (fornecedores diferentes com a mesma proposta). Neste caso, ele irá considerar o primeiro valor encontrado, ou seja, o mais próximo à coluna 0, certo? Agradeço novamente.

Comment: Sim, pois ele apenas registra caso o valor seja menor do que o que está na variável, caso seja igual, ele sai do IF sem registrar o valor. Se surgir mais alguma dúvida, pode voltar a comentar que farei o possível para ajudar.